Import string to formula - VBA
I m looping a range, create three strings with the addresses of each cell based on their colors.
Afterwards, I want to use these strings to import a formulas but i receiving FALSE instead of the formulas.
All variables (strGreen, strOrange & strBlue) declare as strings amd seems to get the correct addresses.
I dont use range variables because can not hold more than 255 characters.
What I missing?
        For d = 13 To LastRow
        
            'Clear variables
            strGreen = ""
            strOrange = ""
            strBlue = ""
                                
            'Set GRB name
            GRBName = .Range("A" & d).Value
                
            If dictGRB.Exists(GRBName) Then
            
                For e = 3 To LastColumn - 1
                    
                    'Green
                    If .Cells(d, e).Interior.Color = 11854022 Then
                    
                    
                        If strGreen = "" Then
                            strGreen = .Cells(d, e).Address
                        Else
                            strGreen = strGreen & "," & .Cells(d, e).Address
                        End If
                        
                    'Orange
                    ElseIf .Cells(d, e).Interior.Color = 10086143 Then
                    
                        If strOrange = "" Then
                            strOrange = .Cells(d, e).Address
                        Else
                            strOrange = strOrange & "," & .Cells(d, e).Address
                        End If
                    
                    
                    'Blue
                    ElseIf .Cells(d, e).Interior.Color = 15652797 Then
                        
                        If strBlue = "" Then
                            strBlue = .Cells(d, e).Address
                        Else
                            strBlue = strBlue & "," & .Cells(d, e).Address
                        End If
                    
                    End If
                
                Next e
                        
                'Green
                .Cells(d, LastColumn + 3).Formula = "=Sum(" & strGreen & ")" = ""
                
                'Orange
                .Cells(d, LastColumn + 4).Formula = "=Sum(" & strOrange & ")" = ""
                
                'Blue
                .Cells(d, LastColumn + 5).Formula = "=Sum(" & strBlue & ")" = ""
                End If
         
        Next d



Remove the second equal-sign at the end: .Cells(d, LastColumn + 3).Formula = "=Sum(" & strGreen & ")"

You can remove the conditional operator If strBlue = "" Then to improve the performance then set formula to "=Sum(" & Mid$(strBlue, 2) & ")" to bypass the starting comma.

Have a closer look to the term you want to write as formula:
"=Sum(" & strGreen & ")" = ""

Now strGreen contains something like $A$3,$C$3,$F$3, so you get
"=Sum($A$3,$C$3,$F$3)" = ""

Note that we are still in VBA: The VBA runtime sees that there is a comparison: You compare the string "=Sum($A$3,$C$3,$F$3)" with the string "", and that will always be False. As a result, you write
Cells(d, LastColumn + 3).Formula = False


If you want to write the Sum as formula, simply write
 Cells(d, LastColumn + 3).Formula = "=Sum(" & strGreen & ")"


This is the approach that I would take:

Create a Consts for each color

Helps the code speak for itself without adding extra comments


Write a method to return a Dictionary of the color addresses

Easier add colors
Reusable


Test if the color exists

.Formula = "=Sum(" & Map(Blue) & ")" - Blue Exists
.Formula = "=Sum(0)" - Blue Does Not Exists




    Option Explicit
    
    Sub Test()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim Map As Object
        Dim d As Long, LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
        LastColumn = Columns("J").Column
        
        With Sheet2
            LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Const Green As Long = 11854022
            Const Orange As Long = 10086143
            Const Blue As Long = 15652797
            For d = 13 To LastRow
            
                Set Map = GetRangelColorMap(.Cells(d, 3).Resize(, LastColumn - 3))
                If Map.Exists(Green) Then
                    .Cells(d, LastColumn + 3).Formula = "=Sum(" & Map(Green) & ")"
                Else
                    .Cells(d, LastColumn + 3).Formula = "=Sum(0)"
                End If
            
                If Map.Exists(Orange) Then
                    .Cells(d, LastColumn + 4).Formula = "=Sum(" & Map(Orange) & ")"
                Else
                    .Cells(d, LastColumn + 4).Formula = "=Sum(0)"
                End If
                   
                If Map.Exists(Blue) Then
                    .Cells(d, LastColumn + 5).Formula = "=Sum(" & Map(Blue) & ")"
                Else
                    .Cells(d, LastColumn + 5).Formula = "=Sum(0)"
                End If
            Next
        End With
        
    End Sub
    
    Function GetRangelColorMap(Target As Range, Optional RowAbsolute As Boolean _
        = True, Optional ColumnAbsolute As Boolean = True, Optional ReferenceStyle _
        As XlReferenceStyle = xlA1, Optional External As Boolean = False)
        
        Dim Cell As Range
        Dim Address As String
        Dim Map As Object
        Set Map = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
        For Each Cell In Target
            Address = Cell.Address(RowAbsolute:=RowAbsolute, _
                ColumnAbsolute:=ColumnAbsolute, ReferenceStyle:=ReferenceStyle, _
                External:=External)
                
            If Map.Exists(Cell.Interior.Color) Then
                Map(Cell.Interior.Color) = Map(Cell.Interior.Color) & "," & Address
            Else
                Map(Cell.Interior.Color) = Address
            End If
        Next
        
        Set GetRangelColorMap = Map
    End Function

Test Results

